# Proceeding from while loop when condition met in R

Tags: r

I am trying to search for a specific file in my current working directory and all parent directories until the first match is found. I'm using a while loop going through the directories directory by directory from my current working directory all the way up until the root directory or until a match is found. If the file does not exist in neither the working directory or none of the parent directories, I want the loop to simple break and print "Root directory reached".

Example:

```
dir <- getwd()
while( !file.exists(paste0(dir, "/my.file")) ) {
    if(dir == "/") { print("Root directory reached"); break }
    dir <- dirname(dir)
}
if(file.exists(paste0(dir, "/my.file"))) print(dir)
```

My question is if there's a shorter/simpler way of this: Do I need the `if` statement below the `while` loop? I added it only to be sure the loop didn't break due to reaching the root directory.

Something along the line of what I want:

```
dir <- getwd()
while( !file.exists(paste0(dir, "/my.file")) ) {
    if(dir == "/") { print("Root directory reached"); break }
    dir <- dirname(dir)
} else print(dir) # This didn't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can use an infinite loop:

```r
dir <- getwd()
dir.prev <- ""

while (T) {
  if (file.exists(paste0(dir, "/my.file"))) {
    print(dir)
    break
  } else if (dir == dir.prev) {
    print("Root directory reached")
    break
  }
  dir.prev <- dir
  dir <- dirname(dir)
}
```

Rather than comparing explicitly to a *NIX root directory (`"/"`) I test if there was a change between iterations to make it system independent. Also, the `else` inside the loop is not necessary but I kind of like it better this way.

Comment: Great! I never considered that making an infinite loop was a thing, and I definetely like the solution for making it system independent. This is probably the least repetitive way, but I can't but help thinking there ought be some sort of `else` statement complementing the `while`-loop. I.e. something like: `while(<this remains true>) {<keep doing this>} then(<when condition is no longer true>) {<do this instead>}`.

Comment: @PålBjartan Yes, that might be handy, but is rarely available in programming languages. The only one I am aware of is Python.